# Can I connect and control 12 Arduino's over USB/serial to my laptop?

Tags: power

I have 12 arduinos, each of them controlling some simple hardware peripherals. I want to interact with all of them over 1 USB connection to my laptop, where I have a python program communicating over serial.

The following seems like it could work: https://www.amazon.ca/Satechi-Power-Adapter-Control-Switches/dp/B0051PGX2I

Are there any electrical/other considerations to take into account for why this would/wouldn't work?

Comment: You want one program to handle 12 serial connections at the same time, as if it was one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, USB can host up to 127 devices, so 12 Arduino boards is certainly not pushing the limit. Having 12 serial ports shouldn't be an issue in either Linux or Windows.

From a practical standpoint, you will have to find a powered USB hub which can support that many devices, or plug multiple hubs together. I'll leave that up to you as shopping recommendations are off topic.

In terms of the hub you use, you need to make sure you don't exceed its maximum current rating. The Arduino boards draw typically around 60-100mA alone. 12 of those and you will need at least 1.2A rating. The hub you mentioned says that it cannot exceed 2A. Depending on what other circuitry you attach to your Arduino boards you may need an external power supply for the boards.